# not print true statement if other statement is true

Tags: python

I'm trying to write this little thing where you give a value to `a` until it matches `b` and you win. So I used `if` statememts for `a>b` and `a<b`. `if a+1==b` 'you are near' gets printed, and obviously `a<b`'s corrispondant statement gets printed too, but I don't want that. How do I only command to print 'you are near' and no other statement if both `a+1==b` and `a<b` are true?

Here's where I'm at:

```
b = 5
a = None
c = 1
while a != b:
    a = int(input('choose'))
    if a +c ==b:
        print ('almost there')
    if a < b:
        print('low')
    if a > b:
        print ('high')
```

Comment: I think you want to use [`elif`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html) ("else if").

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  Your question is answered in any tutorial on `if` statements.  Stack Overflow is not intended to replace these resources.

Answer (score 0):

Use `elif` if you only want run only one branch of your conditions.

```
b = 5
a = None
c = 1
while a != b:
    a = int(input('choose'))
    if a +c ==b:
        print ('almost there')
    elif a < b:
        print('low')
    elif a > b:
        print ('high')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
b = 5
a = None
c = 1
while a != b:
    a = int(input('choose'))
    if a +c ==b:
        print ('almost there')
    elif a < b:
        print('low')
    elif a > b:
        print ('high')
```

Execution branches at if statements and continues in either `elif` or `else`
A new if means an end to the past branching and a start to a new one.